# Calibri fonts not found on Texmaker using LuaLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, texmaker

I am trying to use the 2016 LUMC Beamer template 2.0 on Texmaker for my presentation but I am getting errors that the calibri fonts cannot be found. All font files .ttf are inside the project folder (default folder that I downloaded)  and I tried LuaLaTex and XeLaTex but nothing worked. Until now I was working only with pdfLatex so I am confused if I did something wrong when changing to LuaLaTex (I insert the following command on the users commands lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex), or I have to put the font files somewhere else.

The fonts are loaded in the file  **beamerfontthemelumc.sty**

```
\mode<presentation>
\newcommand\customfont[1]{{\usefont{T1}{font}{m}{n} #1 }}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont[%NormalFont = Calibri.ttf,
 BoldFont = Calibrib.ttf,
 ItalicFont = Calibrii.ttf,
 BoldItalicFont = Calibriz.ttf]{Calibri}
 \setsansfont[Font = Calibri.ttf,
 BoldFont = Calibrib.ttf,
 ItalicFont = Calibrii.ttf,
 BoldItalicFont = Calibriz.ttf]{Calibri.ttf}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setbeamerfont{header}{family=\ttfamily}
\setbeamerfont{title}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{24}{24}}, series = \bf}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{parent=header, size={\fontsize{20}{20}},series = \bf}
\setbeamerfont{author}{parent=header, size={\fontsize{20}{20}},series = \normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{place}{parent=header, size={\fontsize{14}{14}},series = \normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{date}{parent=header, size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{institute in title}{parent=header, size=\small,series = \normalfont}

\setbeamerfont{endtext}{parent=header,size=\huge,series = \normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{endauthor}{parent=header,size=\large,series = \normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{endlink}{parent=header,size=\Large,series = \normalfont}

%%Outline font
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{20}{20}},series=\bf}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{18}{18}},series = \it}

%navigation symbols
\setbeamerfont{navigation symbols}{parent=header, size={\fontsize{14}{14}},series = \bf}

%% This part is unclear yet 
\setbeamerfont{header author}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{24}{24}},series = \normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{header date}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{24}{24}},series = \normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{header number}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{24}{24}},series = \normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{header title}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{24}{24}},series = \normalfont}

% Frame font
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{24}{24}}, series = \bf}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{20}{20}},series = \normalfont}

% block font
\setbeamerfont{block title}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{20}{20}},series = \bf}
\setbeamerfont{block body}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{24}{24}},series = \bf}

% itermize font
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{18}{18}},series = \normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{18}{18}},series = \normalfont}

\setbeamerfont{footer}{parent=header,size={\fontsize{12}{12}},series = \bf}


\mode
<all>
```

I tried inserting `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Calibri}` on the Main.tex file but same errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us how you're attempting to load the `Calibri` font. Do you employ the `fontspec` package?

Comment: @Mico I edited the question.

Comment: Where inside the folder are the fonts in relation to the main file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Both font files and Main.tex file are here **C:\Users\Jane\Desktop\2016-LUMC-Beamer-template-2.0-master**

Comment: Try with a simple hello-world.tex in this folder: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Calibri}\begin{document} hello\end{document}`. Compile with lualatex and if it fails show the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am getting the hello output without errors

Comment: Then change in this file to the beamer class and add one small frame in the document body. If this work copy the \setmainfont and \setsansfont declaration from your theme and try if they work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer First I tried with a small frame and it worked fine. Next I tried it in Main.tex file but a block frame gave me error, I commented out these frames and now seems to work fine. Hopefully it will not give me errors in the actual presentation file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi. I am having the same problem. The hello-world.tex worked, and it also worked when I changed to Beamer class. However, after copying the \setmainfont and \setsansfont declaration from lumc theme, I kept on getting the same error. Any ideas, please? I'm totally stuck. Thank you